# Can't run my app - android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

i am new to android studio, i try to fixed it many times

### This is the message displayed in event logs.

[image]

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please post build.gradle

Comment: You should post your build.grade. But in the interim, try deleting your .gradle folder, clean and rebuild the app.

Comment: try invalidate File->Invalidate caches/Restart

Comment: do one thing, manually go to .gradle folder and delete caches folder, reopen Android studio, it will redownload gradle, this error occurs when your gradle is not properly installed and some backup files are left behind.